# boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor throwing error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use a `boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor` like so :

```
accept_(getIOService(), endpoint_)
```

The error this call returns is :

```
[exec] unknown file: Failure
[exec] C++ exception with description "bind: No such file or directory" thrown in the test body.
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

Verify that endpoint's path is correct.  When I normally observe these errors, it is a path related issue, such as constructing the endpoint with `"tmp/example"` when a `tmp` directory does not exists in the current directory, because I intended to use `"/tmp/example"`.

Boost.Asio's exception is a translation from receiving  `ENOENT` from `bind()`.  The man page for [`bind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html) states that `ENOENT` indicates:

> A component of the pathname does not name an existing file or the pathname is an empty string.